# Payment with authorize.net gives error User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values

Tags: php, authentication, authorize.net

I have followed the link for the payment 
https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php
but the response "User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values".
The code works for developer but it does not work for developer but does not work for the live account.

```
require 'authorizesdk/vendor/autoload.php'; 
use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE","phplog");
/** Make sure that the WordPress bootstrap has run before continuing. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
}

$creditcardno=$_POST['credit_card_number'];
$expdate=$_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'];
$invoiceno=$_POST['x_invoice_num'];
$description=$_POST['x_description'];
$id=$_POST['x_id'];
$email=$_POST['x_email'];
//$creditcardno='';
//$expdate='16/06';
//$invoiceno=$_POST['x_invoice_num'];
//$description=$_POST['x_description'];
//$id=$_POST['x_id'];
//$email=$_POST['x_email'];


//44Wz7d8Zsr2F5zD6
// Common setup for API credentials  
  $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
  $merchantAuthentication->setName("5Tb3S44sLp");
  $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey("****");
  $refId = 'ref' . time();

// Create the payment data for a credit card
  $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
  $creditCard->setCardNumber($_POST['credit_card_number']);  
  $creditCard->setExpirationDate( $expdate);
  $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
  $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

    // Order info
  $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
  $order->setInvoiceNumber($invoiceno);
  $order->setDescription($description);

  // Customer info 
  $customer = new AnetAPI\CustomerDataType();
  $customer->setId($id);
  $customer->setEmail($mail);

    // Bill To
  $billto = new AnetAPI\CustomerAddressType();
  $billto->setFirstName($_POST['credit_card_fname']);
  $billto->setLastName($_POST['credit_card_lname']);
  $billto->setCompany($_POST['x_company']);
  $billto->setAddress($_POST['x_address']);
  $billto->setCity($_POST['x_city']);
  $billto->setState($_POST['x_state']);
  $billto->setZip($_POST['x_zip']);
  $billto->setCountry($_POST['x_country']);

// Create a transaction
  $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
  $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");   
//  $transactionRequestType->setAmount($_POST['x_amount']);
  $transactionRequestType->setAmount($_POST['x_amount']);
  $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);
  $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);
  $transactionRequestType->setCustomer($customer);
  $transactionRequestType->setBillTo($billto);

  $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
  $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
  $request->setRefId( $refId);
  $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
  $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
  $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($response);exit;
```

Is there any thing that we have to setup properly for the live account.

Comment: Are you attempting to use your sandbox credentials in production?  If so, that won't work.

Comment: no no I have change the credentials to live

Comment: I would suggest confirming you have the correct API Login ID and Transaction Key for a production account.  If you need to generate a new production transaction key, you must do so in the merchant interface at https://account.authorize.net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see, the problem over here is that you have set the live API Credentials but the The API environment still set to sandbox,

For that you need to change the last 3rd line from

```
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);
```

to

```
$response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);
```

this would solve the problem.